# Socket Client-Server gets stuck after sending to server side

Tags: java, sockets, io

I need to make a file transfer application with Sockets for my projects. So far I've written a simple client-server communication, but the my code locks whenever I try to recieve character data from clients output to server input. Heres the code:

**SERVER**

```
public class ClientServer extends Thread {

Socket connection;
File file;

public ClientServer (Socket connection){
    this.connection = connection;
    this.start();
}

public void run(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting Client Thread...");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("IO created...");
        System.out.println("input = " + input.readLine());

        String s = input.readLine();

        System.out.println(s);
        file = new File(s);

        if(file.isFile()){
            System.out.println("File " + s + " exists");

            FileInputStream fileOutput = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];
            int length = 0;
                while((length = fileOutput.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    output.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                }
            System.out.println("File " + s + " sent.");
            fileOutput.close();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + " is not a file");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally{
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }               
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int serverPort = 9000;

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

        Socket connectionSocket = server.accept();

        ClientServer con = new ClientServer(connectionSocket);
}
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String ip = "localhost";
    int port = 9000;
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);


    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

    BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter valid file name and press 'ENTER': ");

    String message = userInput.readLine();
    System.out.println("Sending message...");
    out.write(message);
    System.out.println("File name sent: " + message);

    int length = in.readInt();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    for(int i=0; i< length; i++){

        buffer[i] = in.readByte();
        System.out.println("Reading byte... " + buffer[i]);
    }
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Dominik/Desktop/lol/new.php");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(buffer);
    fos.close();

    clientSocket.close();
    System.out.println("Closing");
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's my output, since none of the answers fix my problem (might be me doing something wrong):

**CLIENT**

`Enter valid file name and press 'ENTER': 
C:\\Users\\Dominik\\Desktop\\Login.php //my input
Sending message...
File name sent: C:\\Users\\Dominik\\Desktop\\Login.php`

**SERVER**

`Starting Client Thread...
IO created... 
//Server should sysout the message sent, but it doesn't do so, its just stuck here`

Comment: Do you have the output of the execution ? You have many log which can help to point out the problem

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do. I think you want to transfer the file. Is that right?

Comment: Why on earth is your `FileInputStream` called `fileOutput`? Don't write code like this. Please.

Comment: I want to transfer a file from the server by path input from the client.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to `readInt` in client, but on server side you send only file contents. I looks you forgot to send file size before sending the file.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a line:

```
String s = input.readLine();
```

but you're not writing a line:

```
out.write(message);
```

Add a line terminator to this.

Then:

```
int length = in.readInt();
```

Here you're reading an integer that is never sent. Send it.

Comment: Hmm, so you suggest I should do something like 'out.write(message + '\n')? I did just that and it did not work. The fileOutput was a mistake on my side, didn't pay attention to it. The communication is still locked  on "IO created..." debug message on server side. Any ideas?

Comment: I made **two** suggestions, not one. I don't need to be told what I suggested.

Comment: I did implement the other too, but the code does not reach the int length = in.readInt(), it locks after writing to the server's input for the first time. I appreciate the help man, it's just frustrating becase I'm sitting here without any progress for 2 days straight. If you have any other ideas I will be more than glad to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have errors in your communication protocol:

In your server, after connection, you expect two subsequent strings from client

```
    System.out.println("input = " + input.readLine());

    String s = input.readLine();
```

But client is sending only one (I think you should add a line terminator too as suggested by EJP)

Then Client expects an integer but server is not sending it:

```
    int length = in.readInt();
```

Hope it helps, good luck

**Edit** (after your Edit on Dec 23)

Add in your client

```
out.flush();
```

after your

```
out.write(message + "\n");
```

Then fix the protocol.

I applied all the suggestions you got and I got it to work

Server:

```
    public class ClientServer extends Thread {

        Socket  connection;
        File    file;

        public ClientServer(Socket connection) {
            this.connection = connection;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Starting Client Thread...");
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("IO created...");
                // System.out.println("input = " + input.readLine());

                String s = input.readLine();

                System.out.println(s);
                file = new File(s);

                if (file.isFile()) {
                    System.out.println("File " + s + " exists");

                    FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
                    output.writeInt((int) file.length());
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                    int length = 0;
                    while ((length = fileInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    System.out.println("File " + s + " sent.");
                    fileInput.close();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(s + " is not a file");
                }

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            int serverPort = 9000;

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

            Socket connectionSocket = server.accept();

            ClientServer con = new ClientServer(connectionSocket);
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
    public class Client {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String ip = "localhost";
            int port = 9000;
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.println("Enter valid file name and press 'ENTER': ");

            String message = userInput.readLine();
            System.out.println("Sending message...");
            out.write(message + "\n");
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("File name sent: " + message);

            int length = in.readInt();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                buffer[i] = in.readByte();
                System.out.println("Reading byte... " + buffer[i]);
            }
            File file = new File("C:/test/fromServer.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.close();

            clientSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Closing");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition to all useful answers:
On server side write `length` bytes of file - `output.write(buffer, 0, length);` 
Don't use buffer.length, this will usually cause `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe` because client will close socket right after receiving `length` bytes, but server is trying to write whole 1024*1024 buffer.

Also on client you can get rid of for loop and receive file content like this

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
if (bytesRead != length) {
    ; // handle incomplete file transfer
}
```

Comment: No you can't. `in.read(buffer)` is not guaranteed to fill the buffer. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP It's been a while. You are right, it's worth to compare the length of received message which is returned from `read(buffer)` with the expected length of the file. I think I didn't mention it for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: So fix your answer!

Comment: Done. Thank you for raising my attention!